# Getting bottom overflow error even if inside ListView

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Shouldn't it never fire that error since it's inside a ListView with vertical scroll?

```
body: Center(
            child: FutureBuilder<FiveDaysForecast>(
          future: forecast,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return ListView(scrollDirection: Axis.vertical, children: [
                Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
                    margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 20, 5, 30),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Image.network(
                            snapshot.data.getCurrentWeatherImageUrl())],
                    )),
                Container(width: 100, height: 60, child: ListView.builder(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Container(
                        width: 70,
                        //height: 70,
                        //padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 10, 5, 10)),
                        child: Column(children: [
                          Image.network(
                              "${snapshot.data.getNextFiveHours()[index].getWeatherImageUrl()}"),
                          Text(
                              "${snapshot.data.getNextFiveHours()[index].dateTime.hour}:00",
                              style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                                  fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white))
                        ]),
                      );
                    },
                    itemCount: 5),),
              ]);
            }
            if (_cityName == "") {
              return Text("Search a city");
            } else {
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            }
          },
        )),
```

I'm trying to create a vertical scrollable app that contains an horizontal list view and a container.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the Center widget from the body, and use it only with CircularProgressIndicator?

Comment: Same error, I just tried

Comment: Can you send me a screenshot of the debug console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
body: FutureBuilder<FiveDaysForecast>(
    future: forecast,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      return snapshot.hasData ? ListView(scrollDirection: Axis.vertical, children: [
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
          margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 20, 5, 30),
          child: Column(
            children: [Image.network(snapshot.data.getCurrentWeatherImageUrl())],
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          width: 100, height: 60,
          child: ListView.builder(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Container(
                width: 70,
                //height: 70,
                //padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 10, 5, 10),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Image.network("${snapshot.data.getNextFiveHours()[index].getWeatherImageUrl()}"),
                  ),
                  Text("${snapshot.data.getNextFiveHours()[index].dateTime.hour}:00", style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                    fontSize: 16,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  )),
              ],),);
            },
            itemCount: 5),),
      ]) : Center(
        child: _cityName.isEmpty ? Text("Search a city") : CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
    },
  )
```

Comment: Didn't work. Same error. I tried both editing my code and copy and pasting yours

Comment: I have wrapped your Image.network into Expanded widget. Try the new code

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! Can you explain me why I needed to wrap the Image in the Expanded widget?